# Using addEventListener on multiple elements, avoid TypeError when particular element not found

Tags: javascript, typeerror, addeventlistener, bodymovin

I'm using two simple addEventListener mouseenter and mouseleave functions respectively to play and stop animations (Bodymovin/SVG animations, though I suspect that fact is irrelevant).

So, the following works fine:

```
document.getElementById('animationDiv').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){ 
    animation.play(); 
})
```

(The HTML couldn't be simpler: The relevant part is just an empty div placeholder filled by script - i.e., `<div id="animationDiv"></div>`.

I can place that in the same file as the one that operationalizes the animation code, or I can place it in a separate "trigger" file, with both files (and other others necessary to processing) loaded in the site footer.

The problem arises when I need to be able to set triggers for any of multiple similar animations that may or may not appear on a given page.

If only one of two animatable elements are present on a page, then one of two sets of triggers will throw an error. If the first of two such triggers is not present, then the second one will not be processed, meaning that the animation will fail. Or at least that's what it looks like to me is happening.

So, just to be clear, if I add the following two triggers for the same page, and the first of the following two elements is present, then the animation will play on mouseenter. If only the second is present, its animation won't be triggered, apparently because of the error thrown on the first.

```
document.getElementById('firstAnimationDiv').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){ 
    firstAnimation.play(); 
})
document.getElementById('secondAnimationDiv').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){ 
    secondAnimation.play(); 
})
```

At present I can work around the problem by creating multiple trigger files, one for each animation, and setting them to load only when I know that the animatable element will be present, but this approach would get increasingly inefficient when I am using multiple animations per page, on pages whose content may be altered.

I've looked at try/catch approaches and also at event delegation approaches, but so far they seem a bit complicated for handling this simple problem, if appropriate at all.

Is there an efficient and flexible standard method for preventing or properly handling an error for an element not found, in such a way that subsequent functions can still be processed? Or am I missing something else or somehow misreading the error and the function failure I've been encountering?

### WHY I PICKED THE ANSWER THAT I DID (PLUS WORKING CODE)

I was easily able to make the simple, directly responsive answer by Baoo work.

I was unable to make the answers below by Patrick Roberts and Crazy Train work, though no doubt my undeveloped js skills are entirely at fault. When I have the time, or when the issue next comes up for me in a more complex implementation (possibly soon!), I'll take another look at their solutions, and see if I can either make them work or if I can formulate a better question with fully fledged coding examples to be worked through.

Finally, just to make things clear for people who might be looking for an answer on Bodymovin animations, and whose js is even weaker than mine, the following is working code, all added to the same single file in which a larger set of Bodymovin animations are constructed, relieving me of any need to create separate trigger files, and preventing TypeErrors and impaired functionality.

```
//There are three "lets_talk" animations that can play - "home," "snug," and "fixed"
//and three types of buttons needing enter and leave play and stop triggers
let home = document.getElementById('myBtn_bm_home');

if (home) home.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() { 
             lets_talk_home.play(); 
});
if (home) home.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() { 
             lets_talk_home.stop(); 
});

let snug = document.getElementById('myBtn_bm_snug');

if (snug) snug.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() { 
             lets_talk_snug.play(); 
});
if (snug) snug.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() { 
             lets_talk_snug.stop(); 
});

let fixed = document.getElementById('myBtn_bm_fixed');

if (fixed) fixed.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() { 
             lets_talk_fixed.play(); 
});
if (fixed) fixed.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() { 
             lets_talk_fixed.stop(); 
});
```

At typical piece of underlying HTML (it's generated by a PHP function taking into account other conditions, so not identical for each button), looks like this at the moment - although I'll be paring away the data-attribute and class, since I'm not currently using either. I provide it on the off-chance that someone sees something significant or useful there.

```
<div id="letsTalk" class="lets-talk">
    <a id="myBtn" href="#"><!-- a default-prevented link to a pop-up modal --> 
        <div class="bm-button" id="myBtn_bm_snug" data-animation="snug"></div><!-- "snug" (vs "fixed" or "home" is in both instances added by PHP -->
    </a>
</div>
```

Obviously, a more parsimonious and flexible answer could be - and probably should be - written. On that note, correctly combining both the play and stop listeners within a single conditional would be an obvious first step, but I'm too much of a js plodder even to get that right on a first or second try. Maybe later/next time!

Thanks again to everyone who provided an answer. I won't ask you to try to squeeze the working solution into your suggested framework - but I won't ask you not to either...

Comment: @AndrewL I think what OP is trying to say is that when `#firstAnimationDiv` is not present, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` will be thrown when trying to bind the first event listener and so the second one will never be bound. See the current answer below.

Comment: Thanks both of you. Yes @PatrickRoberts, that is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write your code so that it won't throw an error if the element isn't present, by simply checking `if` the element exists.

```
let first = document.getElementById('firstAnimationDiv');
if (first) first.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {firstAnimation.play();});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could approach this slightly differently using delegated event handling. `mouseover`, unlike `mouseenter`, bubbles to its ancestor elements, so you could add a single event listener to an ancestor element where every `#animationDiv` is contained, and switch on `event.target.id` to call the correct `play()` method:

```
document.getElementById('animationDivContainer').addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
  switch (event.target.id) {
  case 'firstAnimationDiv':
    return firstAnimation.play();
  case 'secondAnimationDiv':
    return secondAnimation.play();
  // and so on
  }
});
```

You could also avoid using `id` and use a more semantically correct attribute like `data-animation` as a compromise between this approach and @CrazyTrain's:

```
document.getElementById('animationDivContainer').addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
  // assuming <div data-animation="...">
  // instead of <div id="...">
  switch (event.target.dataset.animation) {
  case 'first':
    return firstAnimation.play();
  case 'second':
    return secondAnimation.play();
  // and so on
  }
});
```

Comment: This strikes me as an elegant way to proceed. I presume that instead of "mouseleave" (for animation stop()) I'll need to switch to "mouseout" for the same reasons. After I've had a chance to verify, I'll return to grade this as "the" answer, although I'm guessing that the answer from @baao will also work (and is only slightly less efficient)

Comment: @CKMacLeod baao's approach adds an event listener for every element, which uses a lot more memory. Not to sway you or anything ;). The advantage of baao's approach is that it modifies your current implementation with the least amount of changes needed to work.

Comment: @baao directly answers the question as I asked it, but I think your answer and Crazy Train's respond to the question I *should* have asked. Crazy Train's seems more "contemporary" and "advanced' what with the data-attributes and object construction, and so educational for a js plodder like me, and very back-pocketable for future uses. Yours requires the least alteration of the simple existing html (which already features a container, not included in my question). I don't know whether memory will be a major concern for the actual implementation, but I'm noting it also.

Comment: I’d use this one if you can change your html @CKMacLeod, maybe with an object instead of the switch

Comment: @baao not sure I get how I'd substitute an object for the switch. Also, I used the "id" because that's what the generated Bodymovin scripts look  for, and I'd have to re-write in several files built up from them. Maybe next time around!

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - The second, data-animation answer works after I remove the space between `function` and `(event)`. Haven't yet managed to get any version of the first, event.target.id answer to work, however.

Comment: The space you're referring to should make no difference in whether it runs or not.

Comment: I didn't expect it would either, but it seemed to on repeated tests. I tested it again, however, and this time it worked, so I must have made some other mistake. However, getting mouseout to work on the data-animation version seems a little more complicated than I expected it would.

Answer (score 2):

First, refactor your HTML to add a common class to all of the placeholder divs instead of using unique IDs. Also add a `data-animation` attribute to reference the desired animation.

```
<div class="animation" data-animation="first"></div>
<div class="animation" data-animation="second"></div>
```

The `data-` attribute should have a value that targets the appropriate animation.

*(As [@PatrickRobers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1541563/patrick-roberts) noted, the DOM selection can be based on the `data-animation` attribute, so the `class` isn't really needed.)*

Since your animations are held as global variables, you can use the value of `data-animation` to look up that variable. However, it would be better if they weren't global, but were rather in a common object.

```
const animations = {
  first: null,  // your first animation
  second: null, // your second animation
};
```

Then select the placeholder elements by class, and use the data attribute to see if the animation exists, and if so, play it.

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div.animation");
divs.forEach(div => {
  const anim = animations[div.dataset.animation];
  if (anim) {
    anim.play(); // Found the animation for this div, so play it
  }
});
```

This way you're guaranteed only to work with placeholder divs that exist and animations that exist.

*(And as noted above, selection using the data attribute can be done `const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div[data-animation]");` so the `class` becomes unnecessary.)*

Comment: You could also just do `document.querySelectorAll('[data-animation]')` and skip the class.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Great point. The class is redundant. I'll add that as a note.

Comment: lol - looks like another good answer (for a question so elementary, it's hard to find documentation on-line). How to choose among them? ;)

Comment: Take your time and mess around with them. There are pros and cons to each. I forgot to add the event listener, so you'll need to handle that.